# Is there a way to properly display JSX in LaTeX?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple example of jsx code. How can I change the settings so that the indention of the code snippet gets right? Btw in case somebody has a decent link or example of listings which support syntax hightlighting for newer languages like golang please let me know!

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.9}
\lstset{
  float=hbp,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black}\small\smaller,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  keywordstyle=\color{black},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  commentstyle=\color{black},
  columns=false,
  tabsize=2,
  frame=single,
  extendedchars=true,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  breaklines=true,
  backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb},
  breakautoindent=false
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There seems to be a [JSX lexer](https://github.com/fcurella/jsx-lexer) available for Pygments, so you could use the `minted` package instead of `listings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it was suggested in the comments to the questions, there is a [JSX lexer](https://github.com/fcurella/jsx-lexer) available that can help, if you use **minted**.

In order to use minted you need to install an additional package (usually called pygments or python-pygments).

To install the JSX lexer, you need to run as administrator:

```
pip install jsx-lexer
```

After that, the "jsx" language should be recognized by minted:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{jsx}
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloMessage name="Taylor" />,
  document.getElementById('hello-example')
);
  \end{minted}

  \caption{Example of JSX code}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Remember that you need to pass the `-shell-escape` flag to `pdflatex` in order to use minted.

This should be the result:

[image: Example JSX code in Latex]